# Is H.264 used with CRF 0 really strictly lossless?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, lossless-compression

I am surprised by how small files are when encoded in ffmpeg with the libx264 codec in Constant Rate Factor mode equals zero (-crf 0) that, according to the documentation, is "lossless".

I would like to make sure what the word "lossless" here means. I would like to know if it follows my personal definition of lossless video: **After encoding a video, you can confidently bet the life of your mother that, once you play it, the numerical values in the pixels of the restored video will be identically equal (within maybe a factor 0.00001 due to the floating point arithmetic) to the original.**

Does the H.264 lossless encoding follow my definition, or do they call it "lossless" because it is visually very close, very beautiful, whatever... ?

Comment: See https://video.stackexchange.com/q/16674/1871

Comment: That question is just a clueless user that didn't know about 4:4:4 chroma sampling.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not, only for 8 bit that is true. Only qp 0 is lossless for 10 bit, since that requires high444 profile, not high 10 that does not support lossless but crf 0 does not block high 10 profile. Check in mediainfo that it is correct profile, always.